# Vertical and multiple histograms with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

Is there a package or code to make this graphic (https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOc7F.png) with ggplot?
I know there's a way with facet_grid, but I need it to be one graphic, not a facet.
I also know I could use violin graph, but I don't want probability density function or similar.

I tried with facet_grid anyway, but my data is divided in factors and each factor hasn't the same size:

Factor Size
1      20
2      190
3      1140
4      4845

So I get this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbJ7P.png) with

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=x)) + geom_histogram() + facet_grid(~Factor,) + coord_flip()
```

Thanks for your answers.

P.D. Eglish is not my native language, sorry for any mistake.

Comment: The simplest thing might be to remove the facet spacing so it looks like one graphic. Otherwise, I think you'd need to build your own by counting what you want and using something like `geom_tile` to draw the boxes where you want them.

Comment: I read this as you want a density but you don’t want a density.

Comment: Perhaps `ggridges::geom_density_ridges(stat = "binline")` can get you close.  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggridges/vignettes/introduction.html

Comment: If I remove the facet spacing, each histogram will have a different "height", and the first histogram will be really small and can't be seen. Like in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbJ7P.png 

And to clarify I don't want density, I just want frequency in histograms.